# Get number of days between today and specific date python?

Tags: python, strftime

So I have todays date in dd.mm.yy format like this:

```
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    today_betterform = today.strftime("%d.%m.%y")
```

now I have a date in the same format as above and I want a variable with the number of days between today and then.
How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert both dates to `datetime` type:

```
d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(input(), "%d.%m.%y")
d2 = datetime.datetime.today()
```

Then, compute their difference:

```
difference = d2 - d1
```

And divide it by one day:

```
difference_in_days = difference / datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Now, `difference_in_days` is the number of days between `d1` and `d2`.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend transforming your `today` variable to a string.

To get the difference in days, you should just subtract two datetime objects from each other.

```
import datetime

# setup dates
previous_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("05-27-2018", '%m-%d-%Y')
today = datetime.datetime.today()

# compute difference
ndays = (today - previous_date).days

# print output
print(ndays)
```

This outputs

```
173
```